# Visual Studio 2022 - Properties Screen is partial

Tags: frameworks, visual-studio-2022

I need to target my Visual Studio 2022 to target .NET 4.0 target framework. I followed the following link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/revamped-project-properties-ui/
however the same screen look different on my machine, and the "application" group does not appear...Please see my screen below.
what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a Python project, it has a different set of properties than a C# SDK-style project as described in the referenced blog post.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy for your reply, Actually, I searched for this option in order to be able to change the .NET Framework targets which my project is defaulted with. what other option I have if I can't access the "General" in this properties screen?

Comment: I'm confused.  Why would a python project be associated with a version of .NET at all?

Comment: This is related to Visual Studio. It seems the build process in Visual Studio is written in .NET. When I'm building my project (Python project), I'm receiving the following error:

The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Answer (score 0):

This issue was also reported on the Python Tools for VS GitHub repo ([issue](https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/pull/6851)).  The cause is that by default .NET projects default to 4.0 unless otherwise specified, but VS2022 does not support targeting 4.0.  The workaround is to add this to your project file to retarget it to 4.7.2, which is supported by VS2022:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkMoniker>.NETFramework,Version=$(TargetFrameworkVersion)</TargetFrameworkMoniker>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thank You very much Jimmy, this solved the original error message. I'm now getting a new mysterious message..."The "RunPythonCommand" task returned false but did not log an error." Have no Idea why is it showing this...  It started to popup instead of the previous "The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found". er a search I did, it seems that this is a known issue, and I need to recreate my entire project...I will skip as those build errors does not prevent the actual build. Thanks Again